# How can I use Jenkins in MS VSTS to build Pull Requests?

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I tried to connect my Jenkins server to VSTS repo by following this Link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/

[image]

However, the options are different from the tutorial.
There is no way to set a rule for Pull Request, which is what I am trying to do.

I set a new build definition to make the Jenkins build work on every commit, but doesn't work for Pull Request.

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
Which version of TFS Plugin is installed (if any) in your Jenkins server?  
Which version of Jenkins do you use?  
Have you selected version 2.* of the `Queue Jenkins Job` task in your build definition?  
Have you configured your Jenkins job as explained on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin#git-1)?

Answer (score 0):

To queue Jenkins job for VSTS pull request build validation, you can follow below steps:

1. **Create a job in Jenkins**

   First, you need to create a job in Jenkins. If you have already create, then skip this step.
2. **Create and configure build definition for PR build validation**

   Seems you already created a build definition named Jenkins, then add 
   Jenkins Queue Job task.

   If you didn’t configure your Jenkins as an endpoint in your VSTS project, you can click New button to specify server URL, username and password to login the Jenkins.
   Then specify the Jenkins job for queuing.

   [image]

   **Note:** If your Jenkins setup as a local server (the url as http://localhost:8080), then you need to queue VSTS build by **private agent** which also located in the same machine.
3. Add build policy as the target branch policy

   In the build policy, you can set the Trigger as Automatic, the Policy requirement as Required, and the Build expiration is Immediately.

   [image]

Now when pull request is created or updated for merging into the target branch, VSTS build will be triggered immediately, and the Jenkins job will also be queued during VSTS build.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried this and seemed to be working fine, but the build gets successful only when I try to commit to the target branch (`staging` in my case). Whenever I create a branch policy for PR validation, it gives me a `Job Creation Failed` message with `{"statusCode":400,"body":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Job: project_mayflower-frontend_vsts not found\n\tat hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamBuildEndpoint.getJob(TeamBuildEndpoint.java:269)...` Do I have to make different jobs on Jenkins for Normal Commit and Pull Request?

Comment: It's unnecessary to make different jobs. Can you show the screen shot when the error occur?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please check. It only happens when I make a Pull Request. It works fine when I just push it normally to the branch.

Comment: + For additional information, We use Jenkins 2.107.3 with TFS plugin version 5.133.0. Also, we used multibranch pipeline project in Jenkins.

Comment: @Dawn17 Based on the screen shot, the PR build validation is build with Hosted agent. So please make sure Hosted agent can access your jenkins server. Besides can you show another detail build log (by setting `system.debug` as `true`) which build for normal commit?

Comment: Same issue, work fine when triggered on git push, but not when triggered by Pull Request mechanism